# Stripe identity verification storage

Tags: web-services, security, amazon-s3, stripe-payments, privacy

I am reading the [documentation regarding stripe verification](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification) for managed accounts and I am wondering if it is a good idea to store them as well (as a backup) on a private place where my application has access (like a private bucket on S3 or in a private server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend **against** saving any sensitive info on your end such as their SSN, a copy of their government id or their bank account details. The best solution here is to send the details to Stripe directly as they will store it on their end and not log any of it beyond tracking that you provided those info.

You then listen for `account.updated` events on your Connect webhook endpoint setup in your platform. This will tell you whether Stripe needs more info from that user if `fields_needed` is set and what delay you have to provide the required details based on `verification[due_by]`.

You can also use properties like `legal_entity[ssn_last_4_provided]` to know if you've already sent that information to Stripe or if they might need it. This can be found in the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-legal_entity-ssn_last_4_provided)